# Items not showing in vertical list when resized

Tags: html, css

I have display the products and the right side. It is showing in right format inline. But when I resize the window it should become vertical line and display as one by one through scrolling

```css
.products
{
 display: inline-flex;
 margin-top: 17px;
}
.product-description > a, p
{
 font-size: 10px;
}
.product-description
{
 margin-left: 5px; 
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.product-image
{
 height: 130px;
 width: 130px;
 min-height: 130px;
 min-width: 130px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 11px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.product
{
 width: 154px;
 height: 219px;
 min-width: 154px;
 min-height: 219px;
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.top-row
{
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
}
#row-1
{
 background-color: orange;
 color: white !important;
}
.row-icon
{
 margin-left: 15px;
}
.items-container
{
 margin-top: 20px; /*Remove*/
 height: 300px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
 border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;

}
#container-1
{
 border-left: 4px solid orange;
}
.row-title
{
 margin-left: 15px; 
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 700;
}
.categories
{
 height: 255px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 width: 180px;
 max-width: 180px;
 min-width: 180px;
}
.categories-list
{
 margin-top: 10px !important;
 max-width: 180px;
 min-width: 180px;
}
.category-item
{
 padding-top: 6px;
 padding-bottom: 6px;
 margin-left: 0 !important;
 margin-bottom: 0.5px;
 border-radius: 0 !important;
 border: 0 !important;
 border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey !important;
}
#item-row-1 ul li:hover
{
 border-left: 2px solid orange !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container items-container" id="container-1">

 <div class="top-row row" id="row-1">
  <span class="row-icon"><i class="fa fa-camera  fa-fw"></i></span><span class="row-title">Top Row</span>
 </div>
 <div class="row item-row" id="item-row-1">
  <div class="col-lg-2 categories">
   <ul class="list-group categories-list">
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">vItem 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
   </ul>  
  </div>
<div class="col-lg-10">
 <div class="products">
  
 
 <div class="product">
  <div class="product-image">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.telemart.pk/media/catalog/product/cache/7/small_image/180x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/i/lite2_1.jpg" width="130" height="130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-description">
   <a href="">Huawei Honor 8 Lite (3GB,16GB) With Warranty</a>
   <p class="price">Rs. 32323</p>
   <p>@ asdsa</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="product">
  <div class="product-image">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.telemart.pk/media/catalog/product/cache/7/small_image/180x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/i/lite2_1.jpg" width="130" height="130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-description">
   <a href="">Huawei Honor 8 Lite (3GB,16GB) With Warranty</a>
   <p class="price">Rs. 32323</p>
   <p>@ asdsa</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="product">
  <div class="product-image">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.telemart.pk/media/catalog/product/cache/7/small_image/180x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/i/lite2_1.jpg" width="130" height="130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-description">
   <a href="">Huawei Honor 8 Lite (3GB,16GB) With Warranty</a>
   <p class="price">Rs. 32323</p>
   <p>@ asdsa</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="product">
  <div class="product-image">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.telemart.pk/media/catalog/product/cache/7/small_image/180x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/i/lite2_1.jpg" width="130" height="130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-description">
   <a href="">Huawei Honor 8 Lite (3GB,16GB) With Warranty</a>
   <p class="price">Rs. 32323</p>
   <p>@ asdsa</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="product">
  <div class="product-image">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.telemart.pk/media/catalog/product/cache/7/small_image/180x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/i/lite2_1.jpg" width="130" height="130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-description">
   <a href="">Huawei Honor 8 Lite (3GB,16GB) With Warranty</a>
   <p class="price">Rs. 32323</p>
   <p>@ asdsa</p>
  </div>
 </div><div class="product">
  <div class="product-image">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.telemart.pk/media/catalog/product/cache/7/small_image/180x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/i/lite2_1.jpg" width="130" height="130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-description">
   <a href="">Huawei Honor 8 Lite (3GB,16GB) With Warranty</a>
   <p class="price">Rs. 32323</p>
   <p>@ asdsa</p>
  </div>
 </div>

 </div>
</div>

</div>



  
</div>
```

As in the snipplet you can see that browser size is small and thus making the products beneath the list of categories not beside it. Can anyone help me?

Current Output

[image]

Output that I want

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the container holding the categories and product "flex" and put an overflow on the product container. See code below

```css
/**Adde this**/
.item-row {
  display: flex;
}
/**Adde this**/
.categories + .col-lg-10 {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.products
{
 display: inline-flex;
 margin-top: 17px;
}
.product-description > a, p
{
 font-size: 10px;
}
.product-description
{
 margin-left: 5px; 
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.product-image
{
 height: 130px;
 width: 130px;
 min-height: 130px;
 min-width: 130px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 11px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.product
{
 width: 154px;
 height: 219px;
 min-width: 154px;
 min-height: 219px;
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.top-row
{
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
}
#row-1
{
 background-color: orange;
 color: white !important;
}
.row-icon
{
 margin-left: 15px;
}
.items-container
{
 margin-top: 20px; /*Remove*/
 height: 300px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
 border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;

}
#container-1
{
 border-left: 4px solid orange;
}
.row-title
{
 margin-left: 15px; 
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 700;
}
.categories
{
 height: 255px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 width: 180px;
 max-width: 180px;
 min-width: 180px;
}
.categories-list
{
 margin-top: 10px !important;
 max-width: 180px;
 min-width: 180px;
}
.category-item
{
 padding-top: 6px;
 padding-bottom: 6px;
 margin-left: 0 !important;
 margin-bottom: 0.5px;
 border-radius: 0 !important;
 border: 0 !important;
 border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey !important;
}
#item-row-1 ul li:hover
{
 border-left: 2px solid orange !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container items-container" id="container-1">

 <div class="top-row row" id="row-1">
  <span class="row-icon"><i class="fa fa-camera  fa-fw"></i></span><span class="row-title">Top Row</span>
 </div>
 <div class="row item-row" id="item-row-1">
  <div class="col-lg-2 categories">
   <ul class="list-group categories-list">
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">vItem 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item category-item">Item 1</li>
   </ul>  
  </div>
<div class="col-lg-10">
 <div class="products">
  
 
 <div class="product">
  <div class="product-image">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.telemart.pk/media/catalog/product/cache/7/small_image/180x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/i/lite2_1.jpg" width="130" height="130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-description">
   <a href="">Huawei Honor 8 Lite (3GB,16GB) With Warranty</a>
   <p class="price">Rs. 32323</p>
   <p>@ asdsa</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="product">
  <div class="product-image">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.telemart.pk/media/catalog/product/cache/7/small_image/180x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/i/lite2_1.jpg" width="130" height="130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-description">
   <a href="">Huawei Honor 8 Lite (3GB,16GB) With Warranty</a>
   <p class="price">Rs. 32323</p>
   <p>@ asdsa</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="product">
  <div class="product-image">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.telemart.pk/media/catalog/product/cache/7/small_image/180x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/i/lite2_1.jpg" width="130" height="130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-description">
   <a href="">Huawei Honor 8 Lite (3GB,16GB) With Warranty</a>
   <p class="price">Rs. 32323</p>
   <p>@ asdsa</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="product">
  <div class="product-image">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.telemart.pk/media/catalog/product/cache/7/small_image/180x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/i/lite2_1.jpg" width="130" height="130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-description">
   <a href="">Huawei Honor 8 Lite (3GB,16GB) With Warranty</a>
   <p class="price">Rs. 32323</p>
   <p>@ asdsa</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="product">
  <div class="product-image">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.telemart.pk/media/catalog/product/cache/7/small_image/180x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/i/lite2_1.jpg" width="130" height="130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-description">
   <a href="">Huawei Honor 8 Lite (3GB,16GB) With Warranty</a>
   <p class="price">Rs. 32323</p>
   <p>@ asdsa</p>
  </div>
 </div><div class="product">
  <div class="product-image">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.telemart.pk/media/catalog/product/cache/7/small_image/180x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/i/lite2_1.jpg" width="130" height="130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-description">
   <a href="">Huawei Honor 8 Lite (3GB,16GB) With Warranty</a>
   <p class="price">Rs. 32323</p>
   <p>@ asdsa</p>
  </div>
 </div>

 </div>
</div>

</div>



  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `flex-wrap:wrap` to `.product` this `wrap` your `child element` as screen size reduces.

```
.products{
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-top: 17px;
    flex-wrap:wrap; /*Add this*/
}
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcmwn5zw/1/).

Comment: Thank you for the effort! Please check the outputs in pictures

Comment: Welcome @Alen Check this two jsFiddle will solve your issue, we want parent element to be as flex then internally you can wrap and no-wrap. https://jsfiddle.net/mcmwn5zw/3/ and https://jsfiddle.net/mcmwn5zw/4/

Comment: Look at the above answer! He moved the products div only not the whole div!

Comment: @Alen We want our parent to be as flex which is container over-here, then internal .product already declared and inline so it align all image in one line, so after certain screen width if you want you can wrap internal content of .product or you can overflow that.